# get first occurrence of last changed value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get first occurrence of last changed value of "sval" column?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c980809154d41f2accc9f14d569b48f1

**data:**

[image]

in above picture i wanted to fetch highlighted row.

**try:**

```
with LastValue as (
  select t.sval
  from test t 
  order by t.date desc 
  limit 1
)
select t.*
from test t
where t.sval = (select sval from LastValue)
  and t.date > (select max(tt.date) from test tt where tt.sval <> (select sval from LastValue))
order by t.date asc
limit 1;
```

actually the problem statement is i dont want the group by sval first occurence, instead i want the whatever last changed sval so our example after highlighted rows should be returns for ids (22,25).

Comment: Could you list the column names and explain why you got the wrong result ? Everything seems fine here.

Comment: Okay so 1st row of the 74 sval. Is the sval static (given as a parameter) or it needs to be fetched based on the last row of the table ?

Comment: @AymDev, no it is not static, you can find 74 on above row too but the idea is in sval column whatever the last value will be whats to fetch entire that row.

Comment: It is unclear why row 25 is selected. Row 21 also has sval=74, and the max(sdate) is on row 29 ??

Comment: @Luuk why is unclear? he wants the line 25 because of it is the first one matching with 74, the last changed value. And he doesn't want the line 21 because, even having the value 74 too, there are changes on the value after that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try with something like this:

```
select t.value into @lastValue
from test t 
order by t.date desc 
limit 1;
    
select t.*
from test t
where t.value = @lastValue
  and t.date > (select max(tt.date) from test tt where tt.value <> @lastValue)
order by t.date asc
limit 1;
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7d0fc4a6f8f625330cf8d07e96efba11)

Comment: Can someone comment why this answer is not good?

Comment: Not the downvoter but given that the question is completely unclear, it's hard to tell if that's a good answer.

Comment: For me is quite clear what he wants, even existing better ways to explain it. This is not a reason to downvote.

Comment: thanks, @JaimeDrq for clear understanding my question, i think is a very clear question but still dont know why my question is down voted

Comment: hey @JaimeDrq, can we do it without any extra variable? because i will have around 10K + unique id's so will have to use 10k + variables that is not feasible.

Comment: Hi @JunedAnsari, you can replace variable by `with` block. You can try on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f2654b271bf4078f5a018d3f66ec1893

Comment: Hey @JaimeDrq can you help me for two category(id=22,25) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c980809154d41f2accc9f14d569b48f1

Comment: Hi @JunedAnsari, if you agree create a new question, because the solution would be completly different if you have to group by different ids.